# how to add dll files in monetdb?

Tags: dll, monetdb

I have installed "monetdb5" and i am getting the error,

```
      "The program can't start because libmapi.dll is missing from your computer.Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem" when i tried to open "mclient.exe" and 
     "The program can't start because libmonetdb5.dll is missing from your computer.Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem" when i tried to open to "mserver5.exe".
```

I have reinstalled many times and still i am getting the same error.Could anyone suggest me the solution   to solve this issue?

Comment: Could you add some more details please? That should not happen...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually my issue was missing .dll files while opening mclient and mserver.But i resolved the issue by copying all .dll files from lib folder into bin folder.Could you advice me, is that crt way which i copied from lib to bin folder?

Comment: Also, you could try the latest release of MonetDB, Oct2014-SP1

Comment: Also, please make sure that you start MonetDB using the .bat file and not the .exe file...

Comment: Yes.I am using letest release and start using .bat file only

Comment: We are working on a possible fix. Will let you know when it's ready.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try with this installer and tell me whether that works? http://homepages.cwi.nl/~hannes/MonetDB5-SQL-Installer-64-20141211.msi